# Create a client action in Odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to create a client action widget, but getting an error when I click the menu item.
Here is the error.

```
Traceback:
 Error: widget.getTitle is not a function
 _executeClientAction@http://localhost:5014/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager.js:449:27
_handleAction@http://localhost:5014/web/static/src/js/chrome/action_manager.js:670:29
```

***.js**

```js
odoo.define('mobile_basket_verification.BasketVerification', function (require){
'use strict';

var core = require('web.core');
var Widget = require('web.Widget');
// var ClientAction = require('stock_barcode.ClientAction');
// var ViewsWidget = require('stock_barcode.ViewsWidget');
var Qweb = core.qweb;
var _t = core._t;

var BasketWidget = Widget.extend({
// template:'BasketVerificationComponent',
contentTemplate:'BasketVerificationComponent',
init: function(parent,action){
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
},
start: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('Widget Start')
    },
});
core.action_registry.add('basket_verification_client_action',BasketWidget);
return BasketWidget;
});
```

***static.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">

    <t t-name="mobile_basket_verification.BasketVerificationComponent">
        <div class="o_barcode_message d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center bg-800">
            <div class="o_barcode_pic position-relative text-center mt-2 mb-1">
                <i class="fa fa-5x mx-auto fa-exclamation-triangle text-white d-none"/>
                <img class="o_barcode_icon" src="/stock_barcode/static/img/barcode.svg" alt="Barcode" height="40px"/>
            </div>
            <div class="basket_barcode d-flex" style="float:right;width:400px;margin-right:200px;">
            <span>Basket </span>
            <input type="text" class="o_field_char basket_barcode_input" style="width:100px"/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary verify_basket">Add</button>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="o_barcode_lines_header alert mb-0"></div>
        <div class="o_barcode_lines list-group flex-grow-1 d-block position-relative"></div>


    </t>
</templates>
```

***.Menuitem**

```xml
<menuitem id="basket_verification_client_action_menu" name="Basket Verification11" parent=""
    action="basket_verification_client_action"/>
```

**clientaction.**

```xml
<odoo>
    <record id="basket_verification_client_action" model="ir.actions.client">
        <field name="name">Basket Verification Client Action</field>
        <field name="tag">basket_verification_client_action</field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the `AbstractAction` instead.

```
var BasketWidget = AbstractAction.extend({
});
```

Check the [Client actions](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#client-actions) documentation:

> from the perspective of the web client, it is a widget, which inherit from the class `AbstractAction`, and is supposed to be registered in the action registry under the corresponding key (from the field char)